# The LaTex file seems to be coded

Tags: overleaf, journal-publishing, journal

I have prepared a manuscript using the Overleaf platform for a Springer journal. There were no errors but I got feedback from the publishers that say,

*"The LaTex file seems to be coded. Please edit."*

As I am new to LaTeX I couldn't understand what that meant. I replied but haven't got any messages yet. Any assistance on the statement will be really helpful.

Comment: hard to guess what they meant. perhaps they meant that it was in the wrong encoding, but it's almost certainly in utf-8 if you saved from overleaf. Are you sure you attached the right file, the plain text source not a zip file or the output dvi or .....

Comment: Yes, I have submitted the way they have asked me to. I think I should wait a bit longer for their reply. After that, I will reply back here about the issue and their statement.

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: No, I am sorry they haven't replied to me and I gave up on that journal.